# nodejs - Running multiple queries using mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, node.js, express, post

I have an `express` API with a POST request containing the SQL query using [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql). This is working and returns the result as JSON well. The issue I have, is when I want to call this more than once while the other query is still running..

Here is my code:

```
app.post('/select', (req, res) => {
  config.database = req.body.db;

  var sqlQuery = `SELECT ${req.body.select} FROM ${req.body.from}`;
  if (req.body.where !== '' && req.body.where !== undefined) sqlQuery += ` WHERE ${req.body.where}`;
  if (req.body.order !== '' && req.body.order !== undefined) sqlQuery += ` ORDER BY ${req.body.order}`;
  console.log(`Query: ${sqlQuery}`);

  sql.connect(config).then(pool => {
    return pool.request().query(sqlQuery)
  }).then(result => {
    sql.close();
    sqlDone = true;
    console.dir(result);
    res.header('Content-Type', 'Application/JSON');
    res.json(result.recordset);
  }).catch(err => {
    sql.close();
    sqlDone = true;
    console.log('Caught Error:');
    console.log(err);
  });
  sql.on('error', err => {
    sql.close();
    console.log('SQL Request Error:');
    console.log(err);
  });
});
```

The error I get when I call this from my `react` webapp with `superagent` is:

```
Error: Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first.
```

This is irritating as I have to call my API synchronously and wait for the first query to return, before i can call the next one..

Does anyone know how to run multiple queries at once? This would have to be a separate connection as I am running a query on one db then another. Same server though.

Comment: Which sql module are you using?  Does it has a method like isOpen ?  You need to test if the connection is already open before calling connect.

Comment: It's this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

Comment: I can't see such a method, but you could create a boolean variable in your connect routine to set the flag when it has been called then test this before calling again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have managed to get past this by using the [wait-until](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wait-until) library to wait until a boolean is true as suggested by @SPlatten

```
app.post('/select', (req, res) => {
  waitUntil()
    .interval(500)
    .times(60)
    .condition(() => {
      return (sqlDone ? true : false);
    })
    .done((result) => {
      sqlDone = false;
      sql.connect(config).then(pool => {
        console.log();
        console.log('Connected!');

        config.database = req.body.db;

        var sqlQuery = `SELECT ${req.body.select} FROM ${req.body.from}`;
        if (req.body.where !== '' && req.body.where !== undefined) sqlQuery += ` WHERE ${req.body.where}`;
        if (req.body.order !== '' && req.body.order !== undefined) sqlQuery += ` ORDER BY ${req.body.order}`;

        console.log(`Query: ${sqlQuery}`);
        return pool.request().query(sqlQuery);
      }).then(result => {
        sql.close();
        sqlDone = true;
        console.log();
        console.log('Result:');
        console.dir(result.recordset);
        res.header('Content-Type', 'Application/JSON');
        res.json(result.recordset);
      }).catch(err => {
        sql.close();
        sqlDone = true;
        console.log();
        console.error('Caught Error:');
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send({ error: err });
      });
      sql.on('error', err => {
        sql.close();
        sqlDone = true;
        console.log();
        console.error('SQL Error:');
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).send({ error: err });
      });
    });

});
```

Bit of a shame you can't run multiple queries at once but I guess this is a limitation of SQL, not the library.